# No time to error check before crash

Tags: vb.net

When using the HtmlAgilityPack my code is erroring out the minute it hits a snag before i can implement any type of check, for example:

```
                Dim doc = New HtmlDocument()
                doc.LoadHtml(sl)
                Dim searchId = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']").Attributes("value").Value
```

When it hit's this line (after working fine)

```
                Dim searchId = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']").Attributes("value").Value
```

I get the object not set to a reference, i know it's because it doesn't see this value in the html code, i'm not sure the best way to check it isn't empty so i can continue the execution otherwise the application crashes.

Can anyone help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your failing line consists of several property lookups, separated here for clarity::

```
Dim searchId = doc
                .DocumentNode
                .SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']")
                .Attributes("value")
                .Value
```

If any one of these lookups (except for `.Value`) is null, you will get the error you describe. For example, if there's no matching `@name='searchId'` element, the `.Attributes` call will throw the error.

In order to prevent the error, you need to check each result separately *before* trying the next lookup. `doc.DocumentNode` is unlikely to be `Nothing` (assuming that your document is valid and loaded correctly), so something like this:

```
Dim searchId As String
If doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']") IsNot Nothing Then
    If doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']").Attributes("value") IsNot Nothing Then
        searchId = singleNode.Attributes("value").Value
    End If
End If
```

You can shorten the code and prevent the nested `If` by using the short-circuiting `AndAlso` operator. I'd also add a temporary variable for readability:

```
Dim searchId As String
Dim idNode = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//input[@name='searchId']")

If idNode IsNot Nothing AndAlso idNode.Attributes("value") IsNot Nothing Then
    searchId = idNode.Attributes("value").Value
End If
```

Comment: Ah thanks very much Dan! i had a total mental block on how to go about this lol